# 'Found the synthetic property @panelState. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I upgraded an Angular 4 project using angular-seed and now get the error

> Found the synthetic property @panelState. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.

[image: Screenshot of error]

How can I fix this? What exactly is the error message telling me?

Comment: Helped me - https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1880

Comment: You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086234/expected-synthetic-property-transitionmessages-in-angular-15/76927884#76927884

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Make sure the `@angular/animations` package is installed (e.g. by running `npm install @angular/animations`). Then, in your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: How can I check whether it is installed on PC or not.?

Comment: `npm list --depth=0` lists the installed packages on your project

Comment: What is the expected result if already installed.? i can only see these 2: `├── @angular/platform-browser@4.3.5
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.3.5`

Comment: I have installed all the packages for animation and also imported "BrowserAnimationsModule" in the AppModule. But it's still getting the error.

Comment: I had to put this import into my main app module, even though the component that I it was being used on was a child submodule.

Answer (score 261):

This **error message is often misleading**.

You *may* have forgotten to import the `BrowserAnimationsModule`. But that *was not my problem*.  I was importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` in the root `AppModule`, as everyone should do.

The problem was something completely unrelated to the module. I was animating an`*ngIf` in the component template but I had *forgotten to mention it in the* **`@Component.animations` *for the component class***.

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './...',
  animations: [myNgIfAnimation] // <-- Don't forget!
})
```

If you use an animation in a template, you also **must list that animation in the component's `animations` metadata ... *every time***.

Comment: You must be using an old version of Angular, the error is different: `Error: The provided animation trigger "myAnimation" has not been registered!`

Comment: Nope. `^6.0.9"`.  Given that I lazy load most of my components, that may be a factor. But I can assure you I get this error when I omit the `@Component.animations` and it goes away when that declaration is present.

Comment: I recommend you to open an issue on github.

Comment: actually, you need to verify that your app component (the root parent) includes this too

Comment: I experienced this in Ionic while using `ionic serve`. I think `@Component.animations` hadn't hot reloaded because it worked after stopping and restarting the local dev server.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into similar issues, when I tried to use the `BrowserAnimationsModule`. Following steps solved my problem:

1. Delete the *node_modules* dir
2. Clear your package cache using `npm cache clean`
3. Run one of these two commands listed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#installing-rc1) to update your existing packages

If you experience a 404 errors like

```
http://.../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/animations
```

add following entries to `map` in your *system.config.js*:

```
'@angular/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.min.js',
'@angular/animations/browser':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js'
```

**naveedahmed1** provided the solution [on this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15005).

Comment: as i found out today, this issue only occurs if your project is based on the angular quickstart seed. the new angular cli does not use this kind of config file

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is looking for a solution for this when using standalone component
Add this to your main.ts file

```
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{
  providers:[importProvidersFrom([BrowserAnimationsModule])]
});
```

or use

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

 bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
        providers: [
          provideAnimations()
        ]
  })
```

Source:[How to add BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule to Standalone Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504142/how-to-add-browseranimationsmodule-or-noopanimationsmodule-to-standalone-compone)

Comment: I had already tried everything and nothing worked, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome this is also my problem before when it is my first time using angular standalone.

Answer (score 8):

For me, I missed this statement in @Component decorator:
animations: [yourAnimation]

Once I added this statement, errors gone.
(Angular 6.x)

Comment: Actually, there is a page about this in [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations). I should have RTFM

Answer (score 6):

After installing an animation module then you create an animation file inside your app folder.

> **router.animation.ts**

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
    export function routerTransition() {
        return slideToTop();
    }

    export function slideToRight() {
        return trigger('routerTransition', [
            state('void', style({})),
            state('*', style({})),
            transition(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
            ])
        ]);
    }

    export function slideToLeft() {
        return trigger('routerTransition', [
            state('void', style({})),
            state('*', style({})),
            transition(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
            ])
        ]);
    }

    export function slideToBottom() {
        return trigger('routerTransition', [
            state('void', style({})),
            state('*', style({})),
            transition(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' }))
            ])
        ]);
    }

    export function slideToTop() {
        return trigger('routerTransition', [
            state('void', style({})),
            state('*', style({})),
            transition(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }),
                animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }))
            ])
        ]);
    }
```

Then you import this animation file to your any component.

> In your component.ts file

```
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()]
})
```

> Don't forget to import animation in your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Answer (score 5):

All I had to do was to install this

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest --save
```

and then import

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

into your `app.module.ts` file.

Comment: -1; this *mostly* just duplicates the accepted answer that was posted a couple of months earlier, but also misses out the step of passing `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the `@NgModule` decorator. It's *also* virtually identical to [vikvincer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456126/1709587) posted a few hours earlier.

Comment: This will install an incompatible version of the package

Answer (score 3):

The animation should be applied on the specific component.

EX : Using animation directive in other component and provided in another.

CompA --- @Component
 ({

---

---

animations : [animation]
 })
CompA --- @Component
 ({

---

---

animations : [animation] <=== this should be provided in used component
 })

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my @angular/platform-browser was on version 2.3.1

```
npm install @angular/platform-browser@latest --save
```

Upgrading to 4.4.6 did the trick and added /animations folder under node_modules/@angular/platform-browser

Comment: And that also ended up upgrading my whole Angular project to 4.4.6

Answer (score 2):

I got below error :

```
Found the synthetic property @collapse. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
```

I follow the accepted answer by Ploppy and it resolved my problem.

Here are the steps:

```
1.
    import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';
    Or 
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

2. Define the same in the import array in the root module.
```

It will resolve the error. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

For me was because I put the animation name inside square brackets.

```
<div [@animation]></div>
```

But after I removed the bracket all worked fine:

```
<div @animation></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not help to do all suggestions from other posts. My problem solved by adding

> provideAnimations()

to providers specifically where I have

> MatInputModule

module present, not to app root. ( I have standalone root app component).

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';    
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatInputModule],
    providers:    [provideAnimations()],
    ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution to this, do not to import BrowserAnimationsModule in your lazyloaded or child module, import only in your AppModule. If you get this same error while you run your component test, add it to your import array in your test bed. Note. This works if you don't have your own defined animations

Answer (score -2):

```
--
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
---

@NgModule({
  declarations: [   --   ],
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your code. Posting code on its own doesn't help anyone except OP, and they don't understand why it works (or doesn't).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: -1;                                                                     this just duplicates content from the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

> npm install @angular/animations@latest --save

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

this works for me.

Comment: -1; this *mostly* just duplicates the accepted answer that was posted a couple of months earlier, but also misses out the step of passing `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the `@NgModule` decorator.

Answer (score -4):

Simply add ..
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

imports: [
    ..
    BrowserAnimationsModule

],

in app.module.ts file.

make sure you have installed .. npm install @angular/animations@latest --save

Comment: -1                                                                                for duplicating content that's already in loads of other answers here.

Answer (score -4):

Update for angularJS 4:

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/animations

Solution:

```
**cli:** (command/terminal)
npm install @angular/animations@latest --save

**systemjs.config.js** (edit file)
'@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
'@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',

**app.module.ts** (edit file)
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule ],
...
```

Comment: -1; "angularJS 4" is not a thing, and it's unclear what exactly you're trying to express here since you just provide an error message and a hard-to-read code block without so much as a sentence of explanation.