# Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently using angular 4, and I followed the link [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) about how to use Angular Material. This is what I have done so far:

app.module.ts

```js
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import 'hammerjs';

imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
```

I included in my index.html the theme style

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
```

component

```html
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav>
    un idee
  </md-sidenav>

  <!-- primary content -->
</md-sidenav-container>
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-sidenav' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-sidenav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

and the following warning

```
Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected
```

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing MdSidenavModule import and adding it as a dependency to your AppModule

```
import { MdSidenavModule} from '@angular/material'

imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule, MdSidenavModule
  ],
```

Also ensure that, the following line is there in your systemjs config file

```
 '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
```

If you are facing the `BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule` error. Refer to this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241193/angular-4-import-browseranimationsmodule-or-noopanimationsmodule)**

Update : For CLI, update the **`tsconfig-build.json`** file with the below path

```
"paths": {
     "@angular/material": ["../../dist/packages/material/public_api"]
 }
```

Note: Path subjected to change as per your version

Comment: I imported `MdSidenavModule`. But, it caused a compilation error `has no exported member`.
I am using cli so I don't have systemjs config file.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that I don't have the file tsconfig-build either. i do have tsconfig.json but not the one you mentioned

Comment: I did as you suggested
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/material": ["../dist/packages/material/public_api"]
    }
  }
}` But I stil facing the same problem