# Found the synthetic property @state. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application

Tags: angular, animation

I get this error when adding animations into my application.

I found: [Angular 4 - Import BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241193/angular-4-import-browseranimationsmodule-or-noopanimationsmodule). I added the entries to systemjs.config.js:

```
'@angular/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.min.js',
'@angular/animations/browser':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js'
```

I added the imports to app.module.ts (root module):

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
      ...
    ],
    bootstrap:    [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers:    [
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I also installed the animations package:

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest --save
```

What might I be missing?

**edit:**
I know this question looks very much like an exact duplicate of the question I linked, which has various answers. Going through them didn't help though, which is why I am asking for something I am overlooking.

**edit2:**
I also checked [Importing BrowserAnimationsModule Throws 404 - SystemJS Config Issue?](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1880) which aimed at the same solutions already named in Angular 4 - Import BrowserAnimationsModule... (above)

**edit3:**
As the comments mentioned:
I have imported BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationsModule. The code section above was updated to reflect that.

**edit4:**
As I have the animations in a child module of my application, I tried all three variants: Doing the imports in the root module, importing in the child module and importing in both.

**edit5:**
I checked the package versions with npm outdated and, reading [How to update the angular2 version to the latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597780/how-do-i-correctly-upgrade-angular-2-npm-to-the-latest-version), found out about this bug: [`npm update --save` duplicates devDependencies as dependencies](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10531). I realized I had always been updating my packages with `npm update --save`, that's why many packages were outdated. Sadly now they are up2date but it's still not working.

```
Package         Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
@types/jasmine   2.5.36   2.5.36   2.5.52  kidzpointz
@types/node      6.0.78   6.0.78    8.0.1  kidzpointz
jasmine-core      2.4.1    2.4.1    2.6.4  kidzpointz
protractor       4.0.14   4.0.14    5.1.2  kidzpointz
rxjs              5.0.1    5.0.1    5.4.1  kidzpointz
systemjs        0.19.40  0.19.40  0.20.14  kidzpointz
tslint           3.15.1   3.15.1    5.4.3  kidzpointz
typescript        2.4.0    2.4.0    2.3.4  kidzpointz
```

Comment: In your NgModule file (app.module.ts) you have to still do the import statements to import the modules.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I missed to add them to this post. They are already imported.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am facing similar issue when running in prod version

Comment: Sadly I had to work around the issue and am currently not able to test it. Check the answers below. If you find the answer, let me know so I can mark it.

Answer (score 18):

add below imports your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I missed to add them to this post. They are already imported.

Answer (score 14):

If you use animation in one of your components, you should add an `animations` extra-property to the `@Component` decorator.

If, for instance, your component have a `slideInDownAnimation` constant, as described in [the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#adding-animations-to-the-routed-component), you'll have something like this :

```
// others import ... 
import { slideInDownAnimation } from 'app/animations';

@Component({
    template: `...`,
    animations: [ slideInDownAnimation ] // this line is required
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostBinding('@routeAnimation') routeAnimation = true;
    @HostBinding('style.display')   display = 'block';
    @HostBinding('style.position')  position = 'absolute';

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant François! Adding `animations: [ slideInAnimation ]` to _app.component.ts_ was the only thing I needed to do. I didn't need to add the `@HostBinding` lines (those who might, import them from `@angular/core`).

Comment: How do this in service?

Answer (score 1):

I now understand that the error is thrown **not due to the lack of modules importation**:

## app.module.ts

No need to import `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` in here, if you are using `AppRoutingModule, you can import those later in there (*app-routing.module.ts*).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/my' },
  { path: 'my', component: MyComponent,
    data: {animation: 'AnimationsPage'}, // to reference later in animations.ts
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

## app.component.ts

As [François pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862387/6225838), the reference `animations: [ slideInAnimation ]` is required:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { slideInAnimation } from './animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [ slideInAnimation ] // adding the animation name here!
})

export class AppComponent {
  // ...
  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData &&
           outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }
}
```

## animations.ts

```
import {
  transition,
  trigger,
  // ...
} from '@angular/animations';

export const slideInAnimation = trigger('routeAnimation', [
  transition('* => AnimationsPage', [ // referenced in app-routing.module.ts
  // ...
]);
```

## app.component.html

```
<!-- ... -->
<section [@routeAnimation]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</section>
<!-- ... -->
```

So the lack of referencing the animation in the component was the only thing causing the issue for me (since I always included the `BrowserAnimationsModule`).

Answer (score 1):

I was also continually getting this error after importing `BrowserAnimationsModule`, and I had also added the `animations: []` metadata to my component. I was still getting this error, but it turned out that I had added the animations metadata to the wrong component.

Once I added the animations metadata to the *correct component* **and** had correctly imported the `BrowserAnimationsModule` the error went away.

Obviously you might have already tried this but I just wanted to add this answer so that when someone came to this question trying to figure out their problem (like I did) they might see this answer and double check their code.

Comment: Absolutely valid reason and thank you for your answer! :) As the question is already almost 2 years old and I don't have the project available anymore I can't check and mark the answers sadly, but it's a valid suggestion for the next guys browsing this issue to read up on, so thank you for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the old version of @angular/core@2.4.5 which has animations module integrated within in
in version 4 above, animations got its own separate module

I tried to use angular-cli, angular2-cli, angular-seed from github in every configuration I was facing the same issue.

So I downloaded the sample code given in documentation and developed my app above it which is working now. Please refer package.json from that example and make necessary changes before working on it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Inject, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-show',
  templateUrl: './map-show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-show.component.css'],
  // changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      state('topState', style({ transform: 'translateY(50%)' })),
      state('bottomState', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
      transition('* => *', animate(300))
    ])
  ]
})
export class MapShowComponent implements OnInit {....}
```

Adding also to app.module.ts made the trick:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MapShowComponent } from './map/map-show/map-show.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MapShowComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I hope it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I fat-fingered the ID on a child component:

HTML:

```
<childComp @childID ...></childComp>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild("childID")
myChildComp: ChildComponent;
```

Of course, the HTML should have been:

```
<childComp #childID ...></childComp>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found that I wrapped the prime ng autocomplete with a div and that error was coming for that reason.
I removed the div and it is working fine

Comment: Hey rudrakr! I'm not sure what your answer applies to here ...