# Found the synthetic property @visibilityChanged. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application

Tags: angular

Below is the error I'm getting in console window, while running **Angular project in Visual Studio IDE**. But If I run ***in VS Code, there is no error***. Tried to solve by adding,

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

and including it in

```
imports[ BrowserAnimationsModule ]
```

But didn't work.Do anyone know reason for this..Thanks in Advance

[image]

Project link In [VS Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ny_KGOAG4z-OzqL_vFQK2S6htOxR5myl)

Project link in [Visual Studio IDE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1upclsDsNrXI-GKVLqkKJw_IPmyrYuxW_)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241193/found-the-synthetic-property-panelstate-please-include-either-browseranimati/.

Comment: visibilityChanged is probably not in the list of animations in your @Component() decorator.