# Angular 8 Animations Error on Lazy Loaded Module - Found Synthetic Property

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have 2 modules, the `app.module` and a `lazy.module`. As you can imagine, the `lazy.module` is lazy loaded into the `app.module` via router.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule) }
];
```

Now, in the `app.module`, I am importing the `BrowserModule` and the `BrowserAnimationsModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ]
  // ...
})
```

In the `app.module`, I have an animation called `flyInOutAnimation`

```js
export const flyInOutAnimation = trigger('flyInOut', [
  state('out', style({
    transform: 'translateX(-250px)',
    display: 'none'
  })),
  state('in', style({
    transform: 'translateX(0)'
  })),
  transition('in <=> out', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
]);
```

In the `lazy.module`, I have a `FlyoutComponent` that uses the above animation.

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  animations: [ flyInOutAnimation ]
})
```

And the usage of the `FlyoutComponent` is as follows

```html
<app-flyout [@flyInOut]="showFlyout ? 'in' : 'out'"></app-flyout>
```

Now, when you load the component that is using the `app-flyout`, you get the following error

```
Error: Found the synthetic property @flyInOut. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
```

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkza4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) to reproduce the error.

Comment: @S.Robijns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241193/found-the-synthetic-property-panelstate-please-include-either-browseranimati#answer-52508544

Comment: @yurzui this worked, i updated the stackblitz. This kinda defeats the purpose of a reusable component if i have to call out the metadata each time. Make this an answer and i'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calm down Angular compiler you should define `animations` property within `@Component` metadata for the component **where you use** that `@flyInOut` animation.

It's `PersonListComponent` in your case:

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [ flyInOutAnimation ] <=========== add this
})
export class PersonListComponent implements OnInit {
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1dmsr?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy%2Fcomponents%2Fperson-list%2Fperson-list.component.ts)**