# i'm trying to resolve this error BrowserAnimationsModule angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Unexpected synthetic listener @state.start found. Please make sure that:

- Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
imports: [
BrowserAnimationsModule
],
hi ..see this error in my console ..i have import in app.module.ts BrowserAnimationsModule..but i don't fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Found the synthetic property @panelState. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241193/found-the-synthetic-property-panelstate-please-include-either-browseranimati)

Answer (score 8):

i was having the same problem for using material with standalone components and i solve the problem with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72504735/17072417

`import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

`bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, { providers: [provideAnimations()] })`