# How to add BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule to Standalone Component?

Tags: angular, angular14

When I add either a `BrowserAnimationsModule` or a `NoopAnimationsModule` to the imports array of my Standalone AppComponent, it breaks the application.

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    /* ... */
  ],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
```

These are the errors I'm getting when I add any of them:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded.
If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded.
If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

And when I don't add it, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found. Please make sure that:
 - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
 - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@transitionMessages` defined in
 the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see
 https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The `importProvidersFrom` function provides a bridge back to the NgModule world. It should not be used in component provide as it is only usable in an application injector

Add `importProvidersFrom` function to provide BrowserAnimationModule inside main.ts.

**main.ts**

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{
  providers:[importProvidersFrom([BrowserAnimationsModule])]
});
```

[**Forked Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ryvsfk?file=angular-fourteen/src/main.ts)

**Update Angular 14+**

Angular new versions provide two new function **provideAnimations()** and **provideNoopAnimations()** to enable and disable animation. we could use it like this.

```
    import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
        providers: [
          provideAnimations()
        ]
     })
```

**[Documentation Link](https://angular.dev/guide/animations#enabling-the-animations-module)**

Comment: Also good to mention that needs to be imported from here:

import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

Comment: @MarcoMartins Thank you for that. I think it should be a requirement to include imports in code samples. Far too often they are left off, and while they may be obvious they are not always so. Best practice, always include them.  :)

Comment: awesome, should be part of the angular documentation for bootstraping with standalone components

Comment: @Puschie I wanted to let everyone know that Angular has just launched a new documentation site. You can check it out at this link: https://angular.dev/guide/animations#enabling-the-animations-module

Comment: Another reason why Standalone provides no significant benefit but adds complexity and confusion.  ngModules have always worked fine

Answer (score 12):

Just found out that importProvidersFrom should only be used once.

Wrong:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{
  providers:[
    importProvidersFrom(BrowserModule),
    importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule),
  ]
});
```

Correct:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{
  providers:[
    importProvidersFrom([BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule])
  ]
});
```

Comment: Hello, could you point out where you found that information? I have an array in my bootstrapApplication call with the RootCompoennt like:

[ importProvidersFrom(OldModuleA), importProvidersFrom(OldModuleB).....]

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, you can add

```js
provideAnimations()
```

to you providers array.

Answer (score 3):

Angular 17, I got this error when I installed Angular Material without animation, it is necessary to install animation and add configuration in app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideNoopAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideNoopAnimations(),
  ]
};
```

Comment: Just make sure to use `ng add @angular/material` instead of `npm i @angular/material`... Using that, an angular schematic will be executed, doing everything for you. If you're working in a workspace that doesn't support the ng command you might need to execute the schematic manually. In nx for example: `npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add`.

Answer (score 2):

If you see same problem on app.compoment.spec.ts, you also need to add `provideAnimations()` to you `app.compnent.spec.ts`.

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [AppComponent],
            providers: [
                provideMsal(),
                provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
                provideAnimations(),  // need this
                provideAnimationsAsync(),  // might also need this
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    it('should creates the app', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const app = fixture.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the same problem. I fixed it by overrideComponent in my `TestBed` and just omitting the Module.

```
.overrideComponent(
    CourseComponent,
    // since you cannot simply ovveride services that have been injected into Angular Component's
    // providers https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#override-component-providers
    {
      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: CourseService, useValue: courseServiceMock },
        ],
        imports: [
          CommonModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          // BrowserAnimationsModule, -- this cause error related to standalone components API therefore turned off
          MatButtonModule,
          MatInputModule,
          MatIconModule,
          MatDividerModule,
          MatCardModule,
        ],
      },
    }
  )
```

Comment: This seems like a great way to introduce errors later on :) Adding new imports to your component now requires you to keep your test up-to-date as well.