# angular 17 error working with accordion primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, accordion

i have this error in my console :
ERROR Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

my angular is version 17.1.0 new version of angular, I couldn't find any solution for my problem in documents as far as I searched, there is no app.module.ts file in this version

```
this is my app.component.ts :

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/accordion';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    CommonModule,
    AccordionModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'primepractice';
}
```

I tried add `BrowserModule` in imports of app.component but still same error
I tried remove `CommonModule` from imports of app.component but still same error

any idea how to solve it

not working any way please help me

Comment: You are using standalone components so you can't import `BrowserModule` or `BrowserAnimationsModule`. Please check the answers on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/72504142/4962159

Comment: Also, if you want to create a new angular project without using standalone components you can use `--standalone false` when using `ng new`.

Comment: I had to create a new project without using standalone.
thank you for your help