# expected synthetic property @transitionMessages in Angular 15

Tags: angular

I am facing with the following error in Angular 15

ROR Error: Unexpected synthetic property @transitionMessages found. Please make sure that:

- Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
- There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@transitionMessages` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app-module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CategoriaComponent,
    ListaProdottiComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    InfoComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, MatToolbarModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonToggleModule, FormsModule, MatGridListModule,
     AppRoutingModule,KeycloakAngularModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using standalone components, then add **BrowserAnimationsModule** while bootstraping the application.

Example:

// other imports;
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

// by directly providing as options
`bootstrapApplication(AppComponent/AppModule,{ providers:[importProvidersFrom([BrowserAnimationsModule])] });`

// Using AppConfig
`export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = { providers: [importProvidersFrom([BrowserAnimationsModule]), .. other  providers}`
and in main.ts
`bootstrapApplication(AppComponent/AppModule , appConfig);`

Answer (score 1):

Angular material required you to add the `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `imports` as stated in the error message. (You only have the `BrowserModule`).

Comment: I tried to import BrowserAnimationsModule in app.module.ts but the error still remains. The import of BrowserAnimationsModule is never used

Comment: did add it to the imports of the NgModule ?

Comment: Worked well for me. In app.module.ts imported "import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';" and then added to the imports-array. Thanks!